# Reading from the command line in java

Tags: java, input, command, arguments

I am trying to read in values from the command line into variables, using the code below.

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{

    // Read in all of the passed arguments                     
    String address = args[0];
    int port =
        Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int code =
        Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    String msg = args[3];

}
```

When I use the input "" 159 13 "Hello"

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hello"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at client.main(client.java:15)
```

Which relates to the line `int code = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);`

Does anyone know what needs to be changed here?

Comment: It looks like you are parsing a String into an Integer. With the input : `159 13 "Hello"` your args are : `arg[0] = 159`, `arg[1] = 13`, `arg[2] = Hello`. When you execute `int code = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);` it expects a number, not a String. Your input should be something like `X Y Z Hello`.

Comment: Put in something other than the empty string for the first argument.

Comment: args[2] should be related to 13 though

Comment: `""` doesn't produce an argument, so `args[0]` is "159" and `args[1]` is "13". If you supply an actual argument in the first position instead of `""`, you won't get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a way to parse your String ("Hello"); the first thing that comes to my mind would be that you need to catch your Exception (see [Alvin Alexander's page](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00010.shtml) on doing just that in converting a String to an int).

The `try{}` would in this case encapsulate the `int port` and `int code` declarations. `catch{}` would belong underneath the try, of course.

However, in your example, it appears that you're possibly parsing the 159 as a String (`args[0]` would map to the first argument of the input), then "13" is being parsed correctly as an Integer to the `port` variable, and lastly your code is getting hung up on trying to parse `"Hello"` as an integer (using `args[2]`) where you expect it to be mapped to `args[3]` in the `msg` declaration.

Don't forget that Java uses zero indexing! Your code is looking for the following types:

`String`, `int`, `int`, `String`

So if you want to handle situations where a user inputs something **other** than those types, use a `try{}` `catch{}`.

Here's a few links to some relevant documentation on the `try{}` `catch{}`:

[try{}](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html), [catch{}](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html), and a [simple guide to exception handling](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, you need exception handling. Think about what you want to happen when invalid input is entered and handle it accordingly. Any particular reason in your example the method throws instead of using try-catch like below?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String address, msg;
    int port, code;

    try {
        address = args[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        code = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        msg = args[3];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something
    }
    // rest of main method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't convert "Hello" to integer that's the error

the third input is integer and then the fourth input is string